# How to get file paths of files inside a folder including subfolders?

Tags: vb.net, list, path, directory, subdirectory

I'm having an issue with that code. It gets file paths of all files inside a folder including subfolders. 
But when it comes across at a subfolder, the filepath is still generated in this way: "path of the folder where I find files" + "\" + "name of the found file" so when it's a subfolder, the path is incorrect because it doesn't include the subfolder name. I hope you see what I mean.

```
 Dim directoryinfo1 As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FOLDER_PATH)
            Dim fileinfo1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim fileinfo2 As IO.FileInfo
            For Each fileinfo2  In fileinfo1 
            filepath = di.ToString + "\" + dra.ToString
  Next
```

Comment: It's called recursion.

Comment: ok but tell me how I can code it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to look inside di or dra (what ever that is). All the information of the file should be included in the [fileinfo2 variable which is a FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), you have properties for filename/path/... Also, if you want to concatenate paths, I suggest you use [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Carefull using recursion on Folders and Files ! You don't want to lock your machine calling the function on `C:` then getting a `StackOverflowException` or `AccessViolationException` ! If you want to get dirs and files from a lambda path, do it in steps (level/depth) with the appropriate access grants. For example, use dummy child node in a TreeView per directory that contains sub directories without expanding the parent dir.

Comment: @e7ho29sjmsjio - Your question is unclear (what are `di` and `dra`; if you don't have the subfolder name, perhaps it's because you're using FileInfo instead of DirectoryInfo) Anyway, what was the issue, actually, and what was your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is the filepaths try this:

```
   Dim a() As String
    Dim sFolder As String = "C:\Temp"
    If True Then
        a = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sFolder, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Else
        a = IO.Directory.GetFiles(sFolder, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    End If
    Stop
```